# High-level test of Protocol behavior in twisted

Tags: python, twisted, python-unittest

How do I write a high-level test of a Protocol in twisted?

I know you can use a StringTransport to test the low-level protocol details, e.g. it received some raw data and some state change happened, or it responded in some way:

```
factory = SomeFactory()
protocol = factory.buildProtocol("ignored")
trans = proto_helpers.StringTransport("foo", 1234)
protocol.makeConnection(trans)
# ...
protocol.dataReceived("RAW PROTOCOL DATA\n")
self.assertEquals("Hello World!\n", self.transport.value())
```

However, the wire protocol is not so critical right now. It's in flux, and I'm using AMP to not have to think about it too much anyway. What I'd like to test now is the high-level behavior:

- A connection is made, ensure that the protocol notifies the GUI.
- A list of contacts is requested, make sure it sends back the contacts I've supplied.

And so on. For example:

```
serverApp = FakeApplication()   # this contains application state
serverFactory = SomeFactory(serverApp)
testEndpoint = magic.TestEndpoint()   # this class doesn't exist
testEndpoint.listen(factory)

clientApp = FakeApplication()
clientFactory = SomeFactory(clientApp)
testEndpoint.otherSide.connect(clientFactory)

self.assertEquals(serverApp.nConnections, 1)
self.assertEquals(clientApp.nConnections, 1)

assert clientApp.onNewConnection.was_called()  # pseudo-code
```

What's missing is some kind of fake endpoint or bidirectional transport to connect the two protocol objects.

Any tips how to test protocol behavior (rather than wire-protocol encoding) in twisted?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you're not trying to test the low-level details of the bytes on the wire.  You don't want a test harness that lets you move those irrelevant bytes around.

Instead, you want a test harness that lets get away from the bytes and test the application-level behavior that's important to the higher level.

You mentioned you're using AMP.  The AMP API in Twisted works by giving you command objects you can pass to the protocol's `callRemote` API.

If clicking the "foo" button in your GUI is supposed to result in the "bar" command traversing the network with some particular arguments, hook your GUI code up to an `AMP`-alike that just deals with commands.  The implementation of `callRemote` for such a test double might be something like (untested):

```
from twisted.internet.defer import execute

class LocalAMP(object):
    def __init__(self, backend):
        self._backend = backend

    def callRemote(self, command, **kwargs):
        try:
            method = getattr(self._backend, command.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            return fail(NoSuchMethod())
        return execute(method, **kwargs)
```

Now you can invoke application-level behavior without worrying about the protocol.

In a perfect world, a class like this would be distributed with Twisted as part of the testing library for developers using AMP.  Perhaps after you build it you can contribute it upstream.